# Transforming a text from first-person to third-person

Tags: python, nlp

I would like to transform a big string - written in a first-person perspective - to a third-person one. Such as:

> I am very happy. I went to the swimming pool with my friend.

to

> He is very happy. He went to the swimming pool with his friend.

I've searched for a library (any language - Python preferred) that could do that but could not find any.

Does such libraries exist?

If there is no such library, my idea was the following:

1. Use a simple regular expression to change all the 'I' by 'He'
2. Use NLTK to grammar check the text and correct the verbs so it can fit with the third-person

Does it seems like a 'proper' solution?

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but there are certainly many more conversions to make. i.e. mine -> his; me -> him, etc. Not sure if there is a collection of such conversions somewhere or if you could just do some trial and error there.